# `'Props' is not defined. (no-undef)` when using react-native, flow and eslint

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, eslint

I'm adding Flow to my react-native project.
Following the examples at https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/ I've updated by LaunchScreen.js What can I do to make the code compliant according to eslint?

**LaunchScreen.js**

```
  /* @flow */

  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import { ScrollView, Text, Image, View } from 'react-native';
  import { connect } from 'react-redux';

  // Styles
  import styles from './Styles/LaunchScreenStyles';


type Props = {
  foo: number,
  bar?: string,
  };
 // ^^^
 // Her I get 'Props' is not defined. (no-undef) [javascript/eslint]

 [cut……]
```

**eslint.rc**

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "rules": {
    "no-debugger": 0,
    "no-console": 0,
    "flowtype-errors/show-errors": 2
  },
  "plugins": [
    "flowtype-errors"
  ],
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "jsx": true,
    "es6": true,
    "classes": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "react-native",
    "jsx-a11y",
    "flowtype-errors",
    "import"
  ]
}
```